# How to assign variable names to each for loop item - Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi

I would like to be able to iterate through an array of monitors for a computer (pulled through WMI) and then assign each one its own value, so that I can output the results to a csv, with each monitor, mfg, date,sn on its own column.

For example:

```
Monitor 1 MFG     Monitor 1 SN     Monitor 2 MFG     Monitor 2 SN
```

```
   Dell                12345          HP                05156
```

I know how to output to a csv already, just am having problems assiging each to its own variable to use.

```
$Monitors = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\wmi -Class wmiMonitorID -ComputerName "PC"
$Monitors | % {$i=0} {"$_";$i++}
```

This gets me each instance name of each monitor on the machine, but how would I go about grabbing the Serial etc for each ?

I tried using $_.SerialNumberID to pull it out, but am unable to figure it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well...here is how you would do it. It looks like the data for some of the things in wmi needs to be converted to be readable.

```
$Monitors = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\wmi -Class wmiMonitorID    
$obj = Foreach ($Monitor in $Monitors)
{
    [pscustomobject] @{
    'MonitorMFG' = [char[]]$Monitor.ManufacturerName -join ''
    'MonitorSerial' = [char[]]$monitor.SerialNumberID -join ''
    'MonitorMFGDate' = $Monitor.YearOfManufacture
    }
}
$obj
$obj | export-csv
```

Edit...alternative that more closely matches the formatting you are wanting...I think the above is better though personally.

```
$Monitors = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\wmi -Class wmiMonitorID
$i = 1
$obj = new-object -type psobject
Foreach ($Monitor in $Monitors)
    {
    $obj | add-member -Name ("Monitor$i" +"MFG") -Value ([char[]]$Monitor.ManufacturerName -join '') -MemberType NoteProperty -Force
    $obj | add-member -Name ("Monitor$i" + "Serial") -Value ([char[]]$monitor.SerialNumberID -join '') -MemberType NoteProperty -Force
    $obj | add-member -Name ("Monitor$i" + "MFGDate") -Value ($Monitor.YearOfManufacture) -MemberType NoteProperty -Force    
    $i++   
    }
$obj
$obj | export-csv
```

Comment: Worth noting that you need at least PowerShell 3.0 to do your `[pscustomobject]` the way you are.

Comment: Perfect! I was able to previously achieve what you did in your first block of code, but the second block was EXACTLY what I wanted , Thanks!